# Add text to each li node which has children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to add text to each `<li>` node in a `<ul>` list which has children.

Here's an example:

```
<ul class="dropdown">
    <li style="width: 100px">
        <a href="@Url.Action("SearchOrders", "ManageOrders")">Orders</a>
        <ul>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Create Supplier Order", "CreateSupplierOrder", "ManageOrders")</li> 
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Checkout Supplier Orders", "DisplaySupplierOrdersToCheckout", "ManageOrders")</li>
            <li>
                <a href="@Url.Action("SearchByOrders", "RefundOrder")">Issue a refund</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("By Orders", "SearchByOrders", "RefundOrder")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("By Customer", "SearchByCustomers", "RefundOrder")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("By items", "SearchByItems", "RefundOrder")</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("List Orders", "SearchOrders", "ManageOrders")</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

In this example, I want to detect that `<a href="@Url.Action("SearchByOrders", "RefundOrder")">Issue a refund</a>` has children and so write a script in jQuery that will automatically add a `>` to the text.

So far I have done this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".dropdown ul li:has('ul')").css("background-color", "#DFDFDF");

    var listItems = $(".dropdown ul li:has('ul')");

    listItems.each(function(idx, li) {
        var liText = li.text;

        li.text = (liText + " >");
    });
});
```

The first part of the code works and indicates by color that the node has children, but the text is not changed.

I have also tried this:

```
$(".dropdown ul li:has('ul')").text(" >");
```

Or:

```
$(".dropdown ul li:has('ul')").append(" >");
```

But the first one replace the whole text while the second append the text **on a new line**, which is not the wanted effect.

Can anyone help me out? Note that I could simply rewrite the node in my HTML to add the text manually, but I'd like to achieve this via jQuery. Thank you!

[image: Here's a visual example.]

Here's a visual example of the unwanted effect.

[image: Code example]

Here's a chunk of code from the web page, I think it's from the DOM, is it?

**EDIT** I have partially succeeded with my problem. Here's what I have done so far:

```
$(".dropdown ul li:has('ul')").each(function () {
        $(this).html($(this).find('a:first').html() + " >");
    });
```

This does add the text at the right emplacement, however the anchor link does not work anymore and the children does not show.

Comment: For this kind of question, you will have better to provide a jsFiddle and of course relevant rendered HTML markup in question, not this server side code

Comment: @A.Wolff I was on my way to do the jsfiddle, but a user kinda beat me to it by providing a working solution. Sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using append is the right idea, but looking at the code it seems like you want to add the > to the a tag inside the list (it seems likely that the a has been set to `display:block;` which is causing the > to go onto a new line). Try the following:

```
$(".dropdown ul li:has('ul')").find("> a").append(" >");
```

This should add the > to any immediate child a tags.

Comment: Marvelous, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: You should use more readable method `.children('a')` instead of `.find("> a")`. Anyway, +1

Comment: Agreed, .children("a") will do the same job but will make the code a bit clearer

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
$( '.dropdown ul li:has( "ul" )' ).each( function()
{
    var that = $( this );
    var currentText = that.html( );
    var newText = currentText + '>';

    that.html( newText );
}
```

In essence its very similar to Milind's answer, but this way is more explicit and breaks it down into different steps, which may or may not help, who knows :P. And sorry if you think my code looks a bit goofy, I like to use alot of spaces and explicit declarations. :D hope it works! If not there might be a new line character at the end of the currentText, and if that is the case then we will need to find a way to strip that before concatenating the '>'.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you want the ">" appended to the text within the `<a>` element preceding the `<ul>`; right?

The following will do that:

```
$("a + ul", listItems).prev().append(" >");
```

See it in action here: http://fiddle.jshell.net/SZuMC/